# CollectionViewController, should I subclass or implement its delegate/datasource with a normal UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

When I am implementing a viewController with `CollectionView`, whether should I drag drop a `CollectionViewController` from storyBoard then creating a `MyCollectionViewController` class, which is a subclass of `CollectionViewController`?

OR should I just use a normal viewController, add a collection view to it,and implement its dataSource and delegate protocol?

I know one of the advantage for later is that you may have multiple `CollectionViews` under one `ViewController`? But what other pros and cons?

And how it applies to the `TableViewController`, as they are quite similar to each other.

Answer (score 1):

UICollectionViewController inherits from UIViewController, so it essentially is a UIViewController with a UICollectionView and some built-in functionality.  Per the documentation, this functionality is:

> If the collection view controller has an assigned nib file or was
>   loaded from a storyboard, it loads its view from the corresponding nib
>   file or storyboard. If you create the collection view controller
>   programmatically, it automatically creates a new unconfigured
>   collection view object, which you can access using the collectionView
>   property.
>
> When loading a collection view from a storyboard or nib file, the data
>   source and delegate objects for the collection view are obtained from
>   the nib file. If a data source or delegate is not specified, the
>   collection view controller assigns itself to the unspecified role.
>
> When the collection view is about to appear for the first time, the
>   collection view controller reloads the collection view data. It also
>   clears the current selection every time the view is displayed. You can
>   change this behavior by setting the value of the
>   clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear property to NO.

I prefer to always subclass UIViewController and add a UICollectionView in storyboard. This means that my subclass has to implement the UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate protocols and I have to set them in storyboard,  and I have to make sure that when the view controller appears that I reload the collection view.  But because I implement the behavior myself, it feels like I have more control. If you tend to use the regular, default behavior, then perhaps go with the UICollectionViewController to save time.

I feel exactly the same way about UITableViewController and UIViewController with a UITableView - I prefer the latter for exactly the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your UI will have only `CollectionView`, use `CollectionViewController`.

This rule applies for `tableViews` also.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I started to follow a different approach in general. I use plain UIViewController to wich I add UITableView or UICollectionView. In the controller I only create a IBOutlet for the view.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
}
```

Next I create a separate object as my datasource

```
class MyDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    init(with tableView: UITableView){
        //Register cells, configure tableview, etc
    }
    numberOf...
    cellForRowAt...
}
```

Then in my view controller, i have a lazy var with the datasource:

```
lazy var dataSource: MyDataSource = { return MyDataSource(with: self.tableView) }()
```

And finally in viewDidLoad I set the datasource to the tableview:

```
tableView.dataSource = dataSource
```

By doing this, you can keep your viewcontroller really clean and small as it should be. You prevent the MVC (massive view controller) problem and follow the principle of single responsibilities. Also your datasource is now reusable across multiple view controllers.